# Array.some is not working inside my React component, but Array.map is

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

I'm trying to use `Array.prototype.some()` inside my React component to determine if my array of objects has a certain value, but I'm getting the error `data.some(...) is not a function`. `Array.prototype.map()` is working fine.

My `data` is an array of objects from MongoDB.

```
data = [
 {_id: 'foobar', category: 'sleep'}, {}, ...
]
```

Here's the component with the props being passed down:

```
<Component
  data={data}
  category='sleep'
/>
```

The component:

```
import ChildComponent from "../components/ChildComponent";

const Component = ({ data, category }) => {
  return ( 
    <>
      {data && data.some(e => e.category === category) (
        <h3>{category}</h3>
      )}

      {data && data.map(e => {
        return gear.category === category &&
          <ChildComponent 
            key={e._id} 
            e={e}
          />
      })}
    </> 
   );
}
 
export default Component;
```

Why would `.map` work but not `.some`?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do, but I expect you'll find that the error is due to the *return* value of `data.some` being a boolean, which you can't therefore call as a function - which you are trying to do here (you're passing it some JSX containing a h3 tag...)

Comment: Do you mean to use `filter`? Filter will return all the elements in the list where the lambda returns a truthy value.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I left out an &&. I wanted data and data.some() to be true. solved now

Comment: I see, thanks. Basically a typo then (leaving out the `&&` after the `data.some` call). I've voted to close as a typo and hope others will do the same (I don't have a high enough reputation to close questions on my own) now this is clarified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Made a mistake with the logic, should be:

```
{data && data.some(e => e.category === category) && <h3>{category}</h3>}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Array.map(...)` returns an array.
`Array.some(...)` returns a boolean.